# C# Rectangular Array have 3 Sales People and 5 Products

Tags: c#, integer, currency, multidimensional-array

I keep getting the Index Out Of Range Exception. I have to get a sales person number and the product number, then the price before displaying the totals.

I have no clue what is going on because the calculations seem right. Whatever is wrong is probably something small that I just can't seem to figure out. Appreciate the help.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        decimal[,] sales = new decimal[5, 3];
        int spnum;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your Sales Person Number (type 999 to exit): ");
        spnum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        while(spnum != 999)
        {
            int prodnum;
            decimal price;
            decimal amount = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the product number: ");
        prodnum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the total for the product: ");
        price = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

        if (spnum >= 1 && spnum <= 3 && prodnum >= 1 && prodnum <= 5  && price >= 0)
        {
            sales[spnum - 1, prodnum - 1] += amount;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid number. Please try again.");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter your salesperson (type 999 to exit): ");
        spnum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        }

        decimal[] total = new decimal[4];

        Console.WriteLine("\n{0,10}{1,16}{2,16}{3,16}{4,12}", "Product", "SalesPerson1", "SalesPerson2", "SalesPerson3", "Total");

              for (int row = 0; row < 5; row +=1)
        {
            decimal prodtot = 0M;
                  Console.Write("{0,10}", (row+=1));

                  for (int colum = 0; colum < 3; colum +=1)
                  {
                      Console.Write("{0,16:C}", sales[row, colum]);
                      prodtot += sales[row, colum];
                      total[colum] += sales[row, colum];
                  }
                  Console.Write("{0,10:C}", total);

                  for (int c = 0; c < 3; c += 1)
                  {
                      Console.Write("{0,16:C}", total[c]);
                      Console.ReadLine();
                  }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Array indexes in C# are based on 0. In your case, they run from 0 to 2 and 0 to 4.

Answer (score 1):

You declare sales as:

```
decimal[,] sales = new decimal[5, 3];
```

And then you use them here:

```
if (spnum >= 1 && spnum <= 3 && prodnum >= 1 && prodnum <= 5  && price >= 0)
{
    sales[spnum - 1, prodnum - 1] += amount;
}
```

`prodnum - 1` can be greater than 2.